# When creating an animation, why do you message to the UIView class property?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AySlYrel7fc) tutorial. The code snippet can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/team-devslopes/protocol-oriented-views).In some animations, the animation being messaged directly onto the `UIView`. Like the code snippet below.

**Question1:** What property of what class is this UIView? Or is it that we are messaging onto the UIView of the everything on the screen do what's in the code block? I'm just trying to understand which property we are messaging here...

```
protocol Flashable {}

extension Flashable where Self: UIView {
    func flash() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (animationComplete) in
            if animationComplete == true {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 2.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

^^^I don't get `UIView.animate` part. ^^^

And for some it's not directly messaged to the `UIView`.

```
extension Jitterable where Self: UIView {
    func jitter() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.05
        animation.repeatCount = 5
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: self.center.x - 5.0, y: self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: self.center.x + 5.0, y: self.center.y))
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

^^^The above code is more understandable^^^

However when you want to call them both you do:

```
errorLabel.flash()
errorLabel.jitter()
```

**Question2:** what's the difference between the way both animations are written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An animation block is global over all views. A given animation block is free (and encouraged) to animate as many views as it would like at the same time. So this is naturally a "global" function, not tied to any specific view.

In object oriented programming, it is common to implement "global" functions as a static/class method on some relevant class. This improves name spacing (and occasionally has other benefits, such as access to class data). That's all that's happening here. `UIView` is a convenient and expressive place to nest the global `animate(withDuration:...)` methods. But these methods are really just global functions. There's no strict rule that they even have to animate views.

In your `CABasicAnimation` code, there's an implicit global `CATransaction` created as well that wraps up all the current animations. So the "more understandable" version is also a bit more magical and is hiding some of the more complicated parts from you (in a way that can bite you if you don't understand it). The `UIView` version is actually a bit more explicit in what's going on, especially if you animated multiple things together. That's one reason the `UIView` wrapper was added, and why it is typically the better approach for animating views.

Comment: Thanks 1. so theoretically we could have wrote that global function on `ViewController` class and done the same however as for naming purposes it may not be the best choice? 2.  *there's an implicit global CATransaction created as well that wraps up all the current animations* <-- wraps up all animations going in the entire app (though we are usually running one animation snippet at a time, since it's CPU consuming)?

Comment: I'm sure you could make a decent argument about attaching it to UIViewController - after all some may consider animation a part of the "C" in MVC. But the truth is just about anything you can animate is a UIView or one of it's subclasses, and I consider animations to be a part of the "V" in MVC. As part of Swift 3, there's been a strong move towards more "action-oriented" naming of things. Maybe thinking in those terms you can see where they put it in the right place long before Swift came around. :-)

Comment: Can you please answer the 2nd question of my comment?

Comment: `UIViewController` would be awkward because there's no requirement that view controllers exist, but it could have gone there. `CATransaction` groups animations together. All animations that are created in the same event loop, by default, are joined by an implicit transaction. (Explicit transactions are managed by `begin()` and `commit()`.) It's not a matter of "running one animation snippet a time." Various animations may interact (animating the same property) and need to be coordinated, and must work together for rendering purposes.

Comment: Remember that CoreAnimation animations don't just call `setCenter:` over and over again (that's how animations used to work, and how UIKitDynamics work). Animations are composited into layers in parallel (often several frames simultaneously), and draw operations may be optimized out. Transactions also impacts the "actions" system tied to implicit property animations. (Core Animation is actually really complicated under the covers.)

Comment: But the point of `UIView.animate()` was to make a high-level interface to smooth over various complexities of the lower-level `CA` methods and functions.

Answer (score 1):

The [animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate) function is a type method of `UIView`.

This means you can just call the function on the Type `UIView` as you can see in your first code snippet. You can find more information on type methods in the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

The second argument to this function is the animation you want to be performed. This can be an animation on a single view (in this case on `self`) or any other amount of views and animations.

The second version of animation is a [CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cabasicanimation). You set up the animation and then attach it to the specific layer you want.

As the documentation says, a CABasicAnimation is

> An object that provides basic, single-keyframe animation capabilities for a layer property.